# How to add width and height to url coil compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

```
AsyncImage(
                 model = url,
                 contentDescription = null,
                 modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                 contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
         )
```

I would like to add width and height to the image url but I don't know how to do that. I tried .size parameter but it doesn't work. For Glide I used

```
.apply(RequestOptions()
                    .override(width, height)
                    .centerCrop())
```

but I don't know how to use it in coil.

Comment: Your backend API should support such a feature! if it has, read it document!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Modifier** parameter.

```
AsyncImage(
    // other code
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
    .data(url)
    .size(your size)
    .build(),
    modifier = Modifier
              .size(50.dp)
)
```

Comment: but I would like to add resolution to url to let server know which resolution it should load.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I tried with size but it still does not change the url

Comment: You cannot change the url. Backend should do this